# Button label not refreshing if variable is in array

Tags: swift, swiftui

If the variable comes from an array then the label is not automatically refreshed. Is there a specific reason for that?

```
@State private var categories: [ItemCategory] = getCategories()
@State private var isOn = true
Button(action: {
    categories[1].chose = !categories[1].chose
}, label: {
    Text(categories[1].chose ? "Add" : "Remove") // not automatically refreshed, only with view change (go to an other and then back)
})

Button(action: {
    isOn = !isOn
}, label: {
    Text(isOn ? "Add" : "Remove") // automatically refreshed
})
```

Update:

Sorry I missed the ItemCategory

```
class ItemCategory: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
    var chose: Bool
    var collapsed: Bool
}
```

Comment: it must be working, your codes has no issue, can you show struct of ItemCategory.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Is `ItemCategory` a class? Please add the code for it.

Comment: Is Itemcategory struct or a class? If it's a class it wouldn't  work with @State wrapper. Change to ObservedObject wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs because `ItemCategory` is a *class*. Whenever you change its properties, the object remains the same. The `@State` property wrapper reacts when the wrapped object is changed, not when only its properties are changed.

Here you can find more information about the difference between a *class* and a *struct*:

- [Structures and Classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html)

---

The simplest solution to your problem is to change `ItemCategory` to be a *struct* (possibly change `Item` as well):

```
struct ItemCategory: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
    var chose: Bool
    var collapsed: Bool

    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you want `ItemCategory` to remain a *class*, you can remove the category object and insert it again to the collection:

```
Button(action: {
    let category = categories.remove(at: 1)
    category.chose.toggle()
    categories.insert(category, at: 1)
}, label: {
    Text(categories[1].chose ? "Add" : "Remove")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Better - use state object

```
@StateObject var categories: Categories = ...
```

Where:

```
class Categories : ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [ItemCategory] = []
    init() {...}

    update(index: Int, row: ItemCategory) {
        self.objectWillChange.send()

        list[index] = row
    }
}
```

And to update view from @Published:

> objectWillChange.send()

You can make changes already in view:

```
Button(action: {
    categories.objectWillChange.send()

    categories.list[1].chose = !categories.list[1].chose
}, label: {
    Text(categories[1].chose ? "Add" : "Remove") // not automatically refreshed, only with view change (go to an other and then back)
})
```

Comment: Why using both objectWillChange.send() and @published to observe one property? Also, you are calling objectWillChange.send() before appending to array.

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing UI (observe value and update on it)

```
import Combine
```

Create a preview:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(list: CategoryList())
    }
}
```

Create a custom model class for category

```
class ItemCategory {
     var chose: Bool = false
}
```

**OR** create a model structure for category, don't require to send object change notification

```
struct ItemCategory {
    var chose: Bool = false
}
```

Create a static list array observing value (you can assign your data list)

```
class CategoryList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [ItemCategory(),ItemCategory()]
}
```

Button text updating by observing in content view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var list: CategoryList
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            list.items[1].chose = !list.items[1].chose
            /// If using a custom model as class, then we have to send notification to update otherwise commenting this line
            list.objectWillChange.send() // send manually update notification cos class is not auto update support
        }, label: {
            Text(list.items[1].chose ? "Add" : "Remove")
        })
    }
}
```